# What is the COM port of the software serial in the arudino?

Tags: arduino, processing

I have a Bluetooth module connected to my RX(0) pin on the Arduino through which I am receiving data.
I am then printing that data using a `Serial.write()`.
These two pins correspond to COM16 in my computer.

I am now able to receive these values into processing and print them again in processing after I set the COM port to 16 in processing.

Now I want to send a particular value out from processing back to Arduino again via serial communication. I figured I could do this with the software serial. 
However, I have a few questions as to how the software serial works:

If I setup a software serial, what is the COM port for the software serial for which I can send values out from processing to the Arduino?

This is the command to set the COM port in processing.

```
 String portName ="COM16";
 myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 57600);
```

I then use `myPort.write()` to send some values back to the Arduino but how do I capture the values in the soft serial?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [Serial Event](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent)

Minimal code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   // initialize serial
}
void loop() {           // you need to define a loop function even 
                        // if not used at all.
}

// This is an interrupt. 
// Code below will only execute when something is received in the RX pin.
void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();  // get the new byte
        // here you can process the received byte
    }
}
```

If you want to receive several bytes before processing them check the example in the link provided, where it concatenates the chars into a string until the `\n` byte is received

The advantage of this approach is that it uses interruptions, so you don't need to constantly check if something is received in the serial port.

PD: I see that in your code you use a baudrate of 57600. Just modify the code above to make sure you use the same speed, otherwise you will not receive anything (or even worse, you will receive garbage)

Comment: Thanks. I always relied in the automatic coloring based on question tags. Didn't know I can define the code manually :)

Comment: It works for some tags, e.g. `c++` and `c`, but for *arduino* it doesn't.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question when I said processing. I'm talking about Processing the graphical tool. To further explain my question. I need to receive data from two serial ports into the arduino. One is from the Processing software.

Comment: I understand that in the PC side you have Processing (the software). However this is actually irrelevant: the Arduino just receives and sends data, it doesn't care which software you use in the other side (it can be a monkey using telnet). My solution allows you to receive data in Arduino and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the other way around: use SoftSerial / AltSoftSerial for the Bluetooth module comms and the Hardware Serial for comms with Processing.

Bare in mind SoftSerial may not be as robust as a proper hardware serial port.Baud rate 57600 should work, but bare in mind higher baud rates may be unreliable.

Alternatively, if the budget/time allows it, you could use an Arduino that has multiple Serial ports (such Arduino Mega, Due, etc. which have `Serial`, `Serial1`, etc.)